# Reallocating Data in an excel file

Tags: r

I am just looking for a way in R to re-allocate the data of a file.
I have multiple columns and I want to store them all under one column with another one next to that indicates the column name, For example:

I have this:

```
A    B    C
a1   b1   c1
a2   b2   c2
```

And I would like to make something like that:

```
Item   Label

 a1     A
 a2     A
 b1     B
 b2     B
 c1     C
 c2     C
```

(Ideally, I'd like to do that for multiple columns. Thus, I suppose this could be done with a for command).

Comment: `tidyr::gather(df)` or with new `tidyr`, `tidyr::pivot_longer(df, cols = names(df))`

Answer (score 0):

Read the excel-data to R with your favourite excel-parser (I usually use the `readxl`-package for this), then reshape the data (see below for code) and write the result back to excel (for example with the `openxlsx`-package).

```
library(data.table)
dt <- fread("A    B    C
a1   b1   c1
a2   b2   c2")

melt(dt, measure.vars = names(dt), variable.name = "Item", value.name = "Label")

#    Item Label
# 1:    A    a1
# 2:    A    a2
# 3:    B    b1
# 4:    B    b2
# 5:    C    c1
# 6:    C    c2
```